# Difference between $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: notation

Would a matrix of size $m \times n$ (with only real-valued entries) be an element of $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ or $\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: $\mathbb R^m\times\mathbb R^n\cong\mathbb R^{m+n}$.

Comment: According to what I know (and also wikipedia), $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ would be correct notation.

Comment: Normally the second one is the Cartesian product of $\Bbb{R}^m $ and $\Bbb{R} ^n$ .

Comment: Also some books do not use either,  they prefer something like $M_{m\times n} (\Bbb{R}) $ .

Comment: So, an $m \times n$ matrix would belong to $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, while a column/row-vector of size $m+n$ would be an element of $\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was of course complete non-sense ^^. Thanks to @Mason. I wanted to read the right thing which would be $\mathbb{R}^m$ $n $ times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why $\mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^n$ is Wrong

Simple counting will explain why an $m\times n$ matrix cannot be identified with an element of $\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R^n}$:  a typical element of $\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$ is an ordered pair where the first element comes from $\mathbb{R}^m$ and the second element comes from $\mathbb{R}^n$.  In turn, an element of $\mathbb{R}^k$ is an ordered tuple of elements from $\mathbb{R}$.  So a typical element of $\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$ looks like
$$ \renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}} (\vec{x}, \vec{y})
= ( (x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_m), (y_1, y_2, \dotsc, y_n ) ). $$
This ordered pair can, in turn, be identified with a tuple with $m+n$ elements:
$$ (\vec{x}, \vec{y} ) \sim ( x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_m, y_1, y_2, \dotsc, y_n ).$$
This tuple is an element of $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$, as it contains $m+n$ terms.  But an $m\times n$ matrix contains $mn$ terms.  Thus, unless $m=n=2$, an $m\times n$ matrix cannot be identified with an element of $\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$.

#### Is $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ Right?

Suppose that $A = (a_{jk})$ is an $m\times n$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb{R}$.  That is,
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \dotsb & a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \dotsb & a_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{m1} & a_{m2} & \dotsb & a_{mn} \\
\end{pmatrix}. $$
As noted above, this matrix contains $mn$ terms.  If we were to list out all of the terms as a tuple, then we could write something like
$$ A \sim (a_{11}, \dotsc, a_{1n}, a_{21}, \dotsc, a_{2n}, \dotsc, a_{m1}, \dotsc, a_{mn} ) \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}. $$
From the point of view of counting elements, it is not wrong to suggest that $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.

That being said, I would use some care with that notation.  The notation $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is often interpreted to mean the $(m\times n)$-fold Cartesian product of $\mathbb{R}$ with itself (as a set), or to mean the vector space consisting of real vectors of length $mn$.  There certainly are books which use $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ to denote the space of $m\times n$ matrices, so, again, it is not *wrong* to use this notation.

However, if you want to avoid ambiguity, I would suggest that the notation
$$ M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R}) $$
is a common notation which is much less likely to be misunderstood.